# PET game database has disappeared, new location?

Tags: commodore-pet

Some time ago I was pointed to a great site with PET games.... which has since been hijacked. Does anyone know if this moved to a new location? Google fails to turn up anything related, although Google these days...

Do not click this:

commodoregamebase.com

Comment: What's wrong with https://www.gamesdatabase.org/system-commodore_pet.aspx ?

Comment: Added site, did not want to link to scam ads, but here you go. Wayback links to the scam. What's wrong is that the one you link to has about a dozen games and the other had everything I had ever heard of.

Comment: If the site is scammy, just list the site name without making it a link. Anybody who wants to visit can copy and paste, and you won't be elevating the site in search engines.

Comment: Wayback links to the scam? <https://web.archive.org/web/20190614071757/https://www.commodoregamebase.com/> looks legit-ish.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz So, do you agree that your statement "Google fails to turn up anything related" is factually incorrect?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for only a link, which is not a suitable subject question for a QA site.

Comment: Compare <https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/>, though.

Comment: @Tommy - seems like the answer right below demonstrates otherwise :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Site is back
[www.commodoregames.net](http://www.commodoregames.net)

Comment: It seems to answer the question to me? Question is “PET game database has disappeared, new location?” and this answer is a new location.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15197)

Comment: @Raffzahn the question is literally “where is this site?” There is no other part of the answer. It’s a link-only answer because the question asks only for a link.

Comment: @Tommy You may have noted that this is the default text. Further, it simply qualifies as link only answer as that's what it is. Such are by definition not suitable for this site - RC.SE is about collecting knowledge, not replacing Google. You may ofc argue that the question itself is unsuitable as such is a fitting answer, but then the question is to be closed. Now, adding some explanation about why and how to the answer would make it an acceptable one.

Comment: @Raffzahn I think this answer already “includes the essential parts of the answer” which I do not disagree is only a link. I therefore disagree with you original criticism. If questions that would prompt link-only answers are indeed inappropriate (which I would support) then this question is inappropriate.

Comment: @Tommy "I therefore disagree with you original criticism" Huh? You are aware that the 'original criticism' you're refering to was not written by me but is, as I already mentioned (also note the 'From Review' marking), a default message published by the SE system when marking an answer as 'link only' which this is undoubtedly.

Comment: @Raffzahn I was not aware, having misunderstood your reference to a default message. Unambiguously my error.

Answer (score 2):

The Internet Archive has copies going back far enough to avoid the scammy content; around 2019 the game database content seems to be fully accessible, *e.g.* [games starting with A](http://web.archive.org/web/20190814182035/https://www.commodoregamebase.com/Alpha/PET/a.html). (There are later copies but they are not complete.)

The downloads themselves aren’t archived, but the site hosting them is still accessible *via* FTP.

Comment: The FTP site with the download archive is still online, though: <ftp://8bitfiles.net/gamebase_pet/>.